# How to create a View where circular profile image is split between two views, where second view has only top right, top left corner radius in swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, cornerradius, vstack

I'm learning SwiftUI, and my Profile Screen requires a view similarly shown in this image: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/1c/21/96/1c2196706b947cc9e8f656da98fd2c80.jpg

I have managed to set background and profile circular image but I'm not able to give top-right and top-left corners.

```
    struct ProfileMainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var profile: ProfileViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var carouselState: CarouselStateModel
    @EnvironmentObject var profileManager: ProfileManager
    @State var showExpose: Bool = false
    @State private var editMode = false
    @State private var viewMode = true
    @State private var shouldDisplayProfileCreation = false
    
    @State private var errorMessage = ""
    @State private var showError = false
    
    @EnvironmentObject var shippingAddressManager: ShippingAddressManager
    @State private var authDelegate: AuthDelegate?
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @State private var isEditMode = false
    
    @EnvironmentObject var userPaymentManager: UserPaymentManager
    
    let payments = [
        PayModel(number: "4444", fullname: "", source: PaymentTender.Source.visa),
        PayModel(number: "1414", fullname: "", source: PaymentTender.Source.visa),
        PayModel(number: "2020", fullname: "", source: PaymentTender.Source.visa)
    ]
    
    let fav = ["beltBar", "beltBar"]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack {
                // MARK: - Top View
                VStack {
                    ZStack {
                        Image("backgroundImage")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 150, alignment: .center)
                            .background(Color.charcoalBg)
                            .clipped()
                            .overlay(
                                HStack(alignment: .center) {
                                    if showExpose {
                                        
                                        WebImage(url: URL(string: profile.photo))
                                            .onSuccess { image, data, cacheType in
                                            }
                                            .resizable()
                                            .placeholder(Image("profilePic"))
                                            .indicator(.activity)
                                            .transition(.fade(duration: 0.5))
                                            .scaledToFill()
                                            .frame(width: 100)
                                            .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 5))
                                            .clipShape(Circle())
                                        
                                    } else {
                                        WebImage(url: URL(string: profile.photo))
                                            .onSuccess { image, data, cacheType in
                                            }
                                            .resizable()
                                            .placeholder(Image("profilePic"))
                                            .indicator(.activity)
                                            .transition(.fade(duration: 0.5))
                                            .scaledToFill()
                                            .frame(width: 100)
                                            .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 5))
                                            .clipShape(Circle())
                                        
                                    }
                                }
                                    .frame(height: 100, alignment: .center)
                                    .offset(y: 75)
                            )
                        Spacer()
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Button {
                                print("notificationOnProfile button action")
                            } label: {
                                Image("notificationOnProfile")
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.trailing, 30)
                        .padding(.top, 30)
                    }
                }
                
                // MARK: - Profile Name View
                VStack(spacing: 5.0) {
                    HStack(spacing: 4.0) {
                        Text("Profile Name")
                            .font(.custom("Roboto-Medium", size: (showExpose ? 16 : 16)))
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                        Image("star")
                    }
                    Text("Email")
                        .font(.custom("Roboto-Regular", size: 12))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.fontGrayProfile.opacity(0.6))
                }
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 45, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                
                // MARK: - Payments View
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Payments")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.fontGrayProfile)
                            .font(.custom("Roboto-Medium", size: 14))
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .padding(.leading, 20)
                            .padding(.top, 14)
                        
                        Button {
                            print("")
                        } label: {
                            Image("Pencil")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 20.0, height: 20.0)
                                .padding(.trailing, 22)
                                .padding(.top, 14)
                        }
                    }
                    Divider().background(Color.black.opacity(0.1))
                        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 20)
                        .padding(.bottom, 4)
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 17) {
                        ForEach(payments) { int in
                            Text("int\(int.title)")
                                .padding(.bottom, 20)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .cornerRadius(14)
                .background(
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.white)
                        .cornerRadius(14)
                        .shadow(
                            color: Color(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, opacity: 0.1),
                            radius: 20,
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0
                        )
                )
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 20, bottom: 20, trailing: 20))
                
                
                // MARK: - Shipping Address View
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Shipping Address")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.fontGrayProfile)
                            .font(.custom("Roboto-Medium", size: 14))
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .padding(.leading, 20)
                            .padding(.top, 14)
                        
                        Button {
                            print("")
                        } label: {
                            Image("Pencil")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 20.0, height: 20.0)
                                .padding(.trailing, 22)
                                .padding(.top, 14)
                        }
                    }
                    Divider().background(Color.black.opacity(0.1))
                        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 20)
                        .padding(.bottom, 4)
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 17) {
                        ForEach(payments) { int in
                            Text("int\(int.title)")
                                .padding(.bottom, 20)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .cornerRadius(14)
                .background(
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.white)
                        .cornerRadius(14)
                        .shadow(
                            color: Color(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, opacity: 0.1),
                            radius: 20,
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0
                        )
                )
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 20, bottom: 20, trailing: 20))
            }
            .alert(isPresented: $showError) {
                Alert(title: Text(AppConstants.appName), message: Text(errorMessage), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        
    }
}
```

I will Extract my Payments View and Shipping Address View later for more cleaner code and easy readability. but first I have to give top-right and top-left corner radius. (exactly shown in image) I have scrollView in an entire screen. I have gone though these link
https://www.devtechie.com/community/public/posts/151937-round-specific-corners-in-swiftui
but I don't understand which view to give corner radius ? Any kind of suggestion will be highly appreciated ! Thank You !

Comment: Hello! I had to make some assumptions regarding the design, but is this roughly what you wanted: https://gist.github.com/Baglan/aba055e8a0a98b9ebb7da6178b8e1239 Essentially, I've separated the "Head" and the "Shoulders" into it's own view, "Head & Shoulders", eh? :)

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank u so much :) one more question could you please suggest me where can I put an image to the topTrailing corner in HeaderView ? please see this image , I have marked with yellow. https://ibb.co/HHVXqzj

Comment: Good to know :) as for the bell icon, there are many ways to do it, depending on your design objectives. I've added 2 possible solutions to the same Gist: one scrolls with the content, another stays in place. https://gist.github.com/Baglan/aba055e8a0a98b9ebb7da6178b8e1239. Or, as you suggested, you can just move the added `.overlay()` to the `HeaderView` – that way it would move with the content.

Comment: Just added a third way, right in the `HeaderView`, as I said, many ways :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank u so much! Really appreciate your time and efforts :)